# Update the custom objects inside array without reinitialise

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
 class Person {
   var firstName: String?
   var lastName: String?
   var age: String?

    init(_ firstName:String, lastName:String, age:String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

i have an array of Person Class.

```
var arrayper = [Person]()

let person1 = Person("test1", lastName: "test1last", age: "20")
arrayper.append(person1)

let person2 = Person("test2", lastName: "test2last", age: "20")
arrayper.append(person2)

let person3 = Person("mock", lastName: "mock", age: "20")
arrayper.append(person3)

print(arrayper.filter({$0.firstName!.starts(with: "te")}))
```

now i just want a firstName and lastName but who's name start with "te".and also remove an age property at run time.
i know how to sort by name. but don't know how to remove age from object of array!! i don't want to create an another object and replace by new object.

Any suggestion or better approach. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Use for loop with arrayper.

Comment: Have you tried by setting age property with nil, let newArray = arrayper.map({$0.age = nil}). I think you might not remove the property directly from the Struct.

Comment: this is a sample code and in original code there is more than 30 properties

Comment: Why do you want to remove age object?

Comment: i dont want to use age and dont want to display it

Comment: If you do not want to display it. Do not display it, why remove it? How will you get it back if you remove it?

Comment: also dont want to keep in memory. it keep a large size

Comment: Don't remove the `age` from your `Person` structure. Simply define another structure as `Name` with firstName & lastName property and map the filtered array to this `Name` array.

Comment: @Pushp that makes no sense. 1. It would not take much memory. 2. **How would you get it back when you need it if you remove it?** Did you try the solution posted btw?

Comment: @nayem that would be increasing his memory consumption by creating another array of objects which seems to be his concern.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri 1. at that class have more than 30 property which also contain NSData with large content. 2. i dont want it back in that screen. if i get in another class i will fetched it from coredata

Comment: @Pushp did you try the solution posted?

Comment: no not now.. i just trying  out one by one

Comment: @Pushp seems like it is taking a while for you to try them out.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri i tried your answer but it kind of patch. so still waiting for a better answer.

Comment: @Pushp "_but it kind of patch_" i don't understand what this means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185038/discussion-between-pushp-and-rakesha-shastri).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
filtered = arrayper.filter({$0.firstName!.starts(with: "te")})


class PersonName {
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""

    init(_ firstName:String, lastName:String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}

var personNames: [PersonName] = [] // Initialize
filtered.forEach { (personDetail) in
    personNames.append( PersonName(personDetail.firstName ?? "", lastName: personDetail.lastName ?? "")) // Filtered values append to array
}
```

//output printed

```
personNames.forEach { (personName) in
    print(personName.firstName)
    print(personName.lastName)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the property from the `Class` or `Struct` instead you are allowed to set that particular variable / property to `nil`.

From `Deinitialization` of [Apple Doc.s.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Deinitialization.html)

```
playerOne = nil
```

> The player has now left the game. This is indicated by setting the
>   optional playerOne variable to nil, meaning “no Player instance.” At
>   the point that this happens, the playerOne variable’s reference to the
>   Player instance is broken. No other properties or variables are still
>   referring to the Player instance, and so it is deallocated in order to
>   free up its memory. Just before this happens, its deinitializer is
>   called automatically

Code:

```
let filteredArrayper = arrayper.filter({$0.firstName!.starts(with: "te")})
let newArray = filteredArrayper.map { $0.age = nil; $0.someOtherProperty = nil }
```

Comment: You can do it while filtering. No need to iterate through the array twice.